# Refactoring functions in controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring

I think I should move some functions from controller in AngularJs to external "container", but where? To service?

For example:

```
.controller('ctrl1', function() {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        ... some code here ...
    });
});

.controller('ctrl2', function() {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        ... the same code here as a function submit of ctrl1 ...
    });
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Depends on what the code does, does it need to be in the controller? Does it manipulate $scope bindings joint with the dom? it probably needs to remain in the controller but is it something that gets data and makes it available for the controller, then probably needs to go into a service/factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factory for that:

```
.factory('someService', function(){
       return {
        submit: function(){
           var some_data='Text';
           return some_data;
        }  

    }
    });

    .controller('ctrl1', function(someService){
       var text=someService.submit();
    });

    .controller('ctrl2', function(someService){
       var text = someService.submit();
    });
```

Here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOYJsx0MUgdipg33JtlJ?p=preview)